# How to reference numpy array objects?

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

I have numpy array:

```
>>> data
    dtype([('date', '|O4'), ('value', '<f8')]
```

where `date` object is Python datetime.date object which consists of all days in one year:  [2010-1-1, ..., 2010-12-31] and `value` object is value data for corresponding date.

How can I return value data only for, let's say, September?

Comment: Is the array in order by date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a boolean array to index `data`:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
dates=[dt.date(2010,1,1)+dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(365)]
values=range(365)
data=np.array(zip(dates,values),dtype=[('dates','object'),('value','<f8')])
```

`(data['dates']>=dt.date(2010,9,1)) & (data['dates']<dt.date(2010,10,1))` is a boolean array of the same length as `data`, which is `True` for all dates in September:

```
print(data['value'][(data['dates']>=dt.date(2010,9,1)) &
           (data['dates']<dt.date(2010,10,1))])
```

Comment: Excellent. I was hoping for something like that